В папке Windows подозрительно большой файл "D"
Постоянно сталкивался с проблемой нехватки места на SSD-диске. Сначала удалял ненужные файлы, программы, чистил кеши и временные файлы в temp-папке. Но место постепенно само по себе всё время уменьшалось, будто его что-то «ест». В итоге решил заглянуть в папку Windows через анализатор файлов от Glary Utilities. В папке Windows есть подозрительно большой файл «D» (без всякого расширения), защищённый системой. Через сам проводник, Total Commander или вообще что-то ещё он не виден, только через анализатор и монитор ресурсов. Защитник Windows говорит, что ничего особенного не видит. Он разрастается с непомерной скоростью. Позавчера был 9,5 Гб, вчера - 10,7, сегодня — 13 Гб. Полный путь к нему: C:\Windows\D
В интернете по данному вопросу нет никакой информации, но относительно недавно были заданы два схожих вопроса: I have strange 10gb file named d.sys in my windows folder what is it? и Подозрительный файл C:\Windows\D.sys
Там предполагают, что это файл VeraCrypt или что-то подобное, но у меня ничего такого нет, никакой шифровки дисков я не настраивал и не включал, мне вообще не нужно, чтобы мои диски шифровались.
У них файл находится по такому же пути, только у него ещё расширение .sys есть, а у меня ничего такого. Просто чистый «D». 

Монитор ресурсов показывает, что этот файл активно используют все процессы в системе. То браузер в него что-то пишет и читает, то фотошоп, то оптимизатор памяти... Это что, файл подкачки? Но у меня отключен файл подкачки на диске С:




Так и есть. Это был файл подкачки, который решил перекочевать с раздела D на C, видимо из-за нехватки памяти на первом. Уменьшил размер подкачки и переназначил его на диск С и память освободилась. Очень даже много.
